# SparkSession | Ubuntu | Pycharm not working

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pyspark, pycharm

I'm trying to use PySpark locally on Ubuntu using PyCharm rather than a jupyter notebook in order to build an Electron app. However, when I'm trying to set up a SparkSession, it doesn't work. When I try this:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').appName('Search').enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], columns=['Test'])
myschema = StructType([StructField('Test'),Integertype(),True)])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df,schema=myschema)
print(type(df2))
```

the session opens but it tells me

```
"AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'createDataFrame' "
```

Then, rewrite the above with ".getOrCreate()" and it tells me

```
"FileNotFoundError: [Error 2] No such file or directory "home/...././bin/spark-submit'
```

I guess the set up in Pycharm might be off, but I don't really understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to to use method invocation `getOrCreate()`, not `getOrCreate`. Also, make sure you install `pyspark` inside the python interpreter used for your project in pycharm. You can access it via *Preferences* -> *Python Interpreter* in pycharm.

**Update**:
Try downloading and extracting the spark [binaries](https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.0/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz) (e.g. spark 2.4.0) on your local and then add the following entries in your bashrc (and source it). I'm assuming you're using spark 2.4.0, so the py4j is specific to this version. For any other version of spark, check the py4j version and add accordingly.

```
export SPARK_HOME=/<your_path>/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7
export PYTHONPATH=${SPARK_HOME}/python:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=${SPARK_HOME}/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/<location_of_python_interpreter>
```

Whatever python interpreter you're linking into `PYSPARK_PYTHON`, make sure to use the same python in your pycharm project.

Comment: i did the following and I still have the same error. I've tried it with python3.7 and 3.6 and returns the same error

Comment: it works like a charm ! I get a bunch of errors though  like the following [ 20/04/13 13:34:24 WARN Utils: Your hostname, VB resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface enp0s3) ...  ] but I guess it might due to the local installation.